# Puffing Billy redirect not working with Webmock and Capybara Webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I use an external site to handle my authentication. In my main controller, I do this by redirecting away to the external site which in turn redirects back to my site's `callback` url once the user authenticates.

I'm trying to stub this behavior in RSpec using Puffing Billy.

Here's my controller

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController
  # `root_path` routes to here
  def connect
    some_external_url = "https://partner.co/some/path?foo=bar"
    redirect_to(some_external_url)
  end

  # `auth_callback_path` routes to here
  # The external site will also send over some data in the params,
  # which will need to be stubbed as well in the specs below
  def callback
    data = params[:data]
    binding.pry

    # do stuff
  end
end
```

My `spec_helper` has Webmock and Capybara configured as follows

```
# Set webmock and capybara drivers
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit_billy
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_billy
```

And finally, the feature spec itself does the stubbing and testing

```
before(:each) do
  # Stub the external url so that it redirects to the `callback` action above
  proxy.stub("https://partner.co/some/path").and_return(Proc.new { |params|
    data = params["foo"] == "bar" ? "good data" : "bad data"
    url = auth_callback_url(data: data)

    { redirect_to: url }
  })
end

it "should work" do
  visit root_path
  puts current_url  #=> "https://partner.co/some/path?foo=bar"
end
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the redirect itself isn't working. After visiting the root path and getting redirected to the partner's site, it never *redirects back to my app*, even though I have that configured in the `Proc` object.

Could this be some interference from Webmock? Or did I misconfigure the stub?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

After various iterations of testing above, decided to simplify and see if using the proxy was working as expected when visiting some plain old static page.

Ran the blow code snippet:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :use_puffing_billy) do
    Capybara.default_driver = :webkit_billy
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_billy
  end
end

# spec/feature/my_spec.rb
it "can do stuff", :use_puffing_billy, js: true do
  # 
  # `/contact` is a standard "Contact Us" static page. It requires no 
  # authentication, has no redirects, etc... making it useful for simply
  # testing whether the page loads or not
  #
  # Capybara.app_host         => nil
  # Billy.config.proxy_host   => "localhost"

  visit contact_url
  binding.pry
  #
  # current_url           => "http://www.example.com:51984/contact"
  # page.body.present?    => false

  visit contact_path
  binding.pry
  #
  # current_url           => "http://127.0.0.1:51984/contact"
  # page.body.present?    => true
end
```

It appears that `current_url` does not work but `current_path` does, likely because they use different hosts.

Comment: Are you actually using the puffing-billy driver for that test ?  Since you've set `javascript_driver` but no `js` metadata tag on the test you show it may not actually be using it.

Comment: Also have you checked the value of `auth_callback_url(data: data)` is actually what you expect it to be?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWalpole - I just blindly set both the current and javascript driver as `:webkit_billy`. I'm not using JS for this spec, but I assume it should work either way since `:webkit_billy` will always be the driver? As for the value, I tried to place a `binding.pry` inside the `Proc` block to check the value like you suggested. That `binding.pry` never triggers, so it's not even calling that Proc. Could it be the URL I'm proxying is incorrect in some way? I just provided the base URL+URI but in reality I redirect to that with some query params. Assumed I didn't need to include params.

Comment: Assuming you're using the default Capybara RSpec config,  `Capybara.current_driver` will get set to the value of `Capybara.default_driver` before every test unless you specify `js` metadata which will then set `Capybara.current_driver` to the value of `Capybara.javascript_driver`.  In which case your current test would be using whatever `Capybara.default_driver` is set to, which would generally be `rack_test`.  The `rack_test` driver doesn't support any outside urls (domains are just ignored) so it would not go through the browser/proxy at all.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I removed the line about setting `current_driver` and tagged my spec with `js: true`. It's definitely using `:webkit_billy` as it's current driver, but still hitting the same issue of never actually `call`-ing the `Proc` (since the `binding.pry` doesn't trigger). Does Webmock interfere in any way perhaps?

Comment: It's possible, you should be able to disable it when running feature tests using code like that from the puffing-billy readme - https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy#working-with-vcr-and-webmock

Comment: @ThomasWalpole -Thanks for the advice so far. Your suggestions led me to poke around a bit more.

I ignored stubbing the proxy for a moment and wanted to see if a page would even load as expected when using `:webkit_billy` (it doesn't!). I added an **EDIT** to the question above showing how it might be because of an issue with the host being used. I know PuffingBilly provides config opts to set the host but my knowledge in the area is limited and I'm embarrassing confused on what the proxy is, what host is being set, and what to set it to.

Comment: `contact_url` depends on what you have set for `default_url_options` in your rails test environment. Using `current_path` allows Capybara to fill in the correct host and port for the app instance it started up. Stick with visiting paths unless you have a very specific need for urls (subdomain routing usually)